# tikz image gallery

Tags: tikz-pgf

i need an easy method in tikzpicture to make a gallery of images or \node... entries, each with a caption, following some criteria like `N x P`, where `N` is the number of images/entries horizontally and `P` vertically. For the moment I'm using two variables containing the horizontal space middle to middle between two entries and similarly vertically.
The drawback of doing so is that if i have to change entries order of occurrence, i need to do that on the names and their caption contents without touching the rest of the lines because they contain the coordinates and labels used by captions.
So i'd like to be able to get the same result by simply appending the entries like '\includegraphics...' or '\ticks ...' each with their caption as in the mwe without having to bother about labels and coordinates. It's a bit like what \matrix does for text but here for image-caption pairs.

here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=30mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\tikzset{
  caption/.style = {anchor=north, yshift=-1mm, align=center},
  img/.style = {inner sep=0pt,anchor=north}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}

% following command to force the entry to be of size #1x#2 and the image into
% the \makebox be at the bottom.
% Using \makebox will allow captions to be horizontally aligned if #1x#2 is same
% for all entries of the gallery.

\newcommand{\boximg}[3]{
  \makebox(#1,#2)[b]{\includegraphics[width=#1,height=#2]{#3}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\newlength\x\setlength\x{.2\textwidth}
\newlength\y\setlength\y{.16667\textheight}

    \node at (current page text area.north west) (titre)
    [font=\huge, align=center,anchor=north west] {{titre 1}};
  %  \draw [line width=1pt, yshift=-2pt] (titre.south west) -- (titre.south east);

    \node  at ([yshift=-8mm] 0.5\x,0 |- titre.south)
    (im1) [img] {\boximg{30mm}{30mm}{example-image}};
    \node at (im1.south) [caption] {my image 1};

    \node  at (1.5\x,0 |- im1.north)
    (im2) [img] {\boximg{30mm}{30mm}{example-image}};
    \node at (im2.south) [caption] {my image 2};

    \node  at (2.5\x,0 |- im1.north)
    (im3) [img] {\boximg{30mm}{30mm}{example-image}};
    \node at (im3.south) [caption] {my image 3};

    \node  at (3.5\x,0 |- im1.north)
    (im4) [img] {\boximg{30mm}{30mm}{example-image}};
    \node at (im4.south) [caption] {my image 4};

    \node  at (4.5\x,0 |- im1.north)
    (im5) [img] {\boximg{30mm}{30mm}{example-image}};
    \node at (im5.south) [caption] {my image 5};

    \node  at ([yshift=-\y] 0.5\x,0 |- im1.north)
    (tikz1) [img] {\boximg{30mm}{30mm}{example-image}};
    \node at (tikz1.south) [caption] {my tikz 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Comment: done, you only need to provide im.png in your working directory.

Comment: You may replace `img.png` with `example-image`, then your example becomes compilable for everyone. (`example-image` is provided by the TeX installation through pkg `mwe`.)

Comment: done, i didn't know

Answer (score 5):

If I correctly understood your intention, than to my opinion you not need  `tikz` magic for formation your gallery of images.  It can be organized by set of `\subfloats`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=30mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.18\linewidth}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.5ex,
                             belowskip=1ex,
                             labelformat=simple}
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{}

\subfloat[image 1]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[image 2]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[image 3]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[image 4]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[image 5]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}

\medskip
\subfloat[image 6]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[image 7]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[image 8]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[image 9]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[image 10]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)

**Edit:**
Above solution anticipate, that each rows of images is full. In the cases, when the last row have less images, for example only three, which should be left aligned, than the command `\hfill` had to be replaced with fixed width. For example with new command `\sep` which can be defined as `\newcommand\sep{\hspace{0.025\linewidth}}`. An example of such gallery is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=30mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}


\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.18\linewidth}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.5ex,
                             belowskip=1ex,
                             labelformat=simple}
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{}
    \newcommand\sep{\hspace{0.025\linewidth}}

\subfloat[image 1]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\sep
\subfloat[image 2]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\sep
\subfloat[image 3]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\sep
\subfloat[image 4]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\sep
\subfloat[image 5]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}

\medskip
\subfloat[image 6]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\sep
\subfloat[image 7]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\sep
\subfloat[image 8]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\sep
\subfloat[image 9]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\sep
\subfloat[image 10]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}

\medskip
\subfloat[image 11]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck-portrait}}
\sep
\subfloat[image 12]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck-portrait}}
\sep
\subfloat[image 13]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck-portrait}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

Since you persist, that solution had to base on `tikzpicture`, here is one of possible solution. It use Ti*k*Z libraries `chain` and `positioning`. For caption is used `label` option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=30mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5ex and 0.025\linewidth,
  start chain = A going right,
   box/.style = {text width=0.18\linewidth,
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                 label=below:#1,
                 on chain=A}
                        ]
\node[box=image 1]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}; % A-1
\node[box=image 2]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\node[box=image 3]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\node[box=image 4]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\node[box=image 5]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};

\node[box=image 6,
      below=of A-1]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};% A-6
\node[box=image 7]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\node[box=image 8]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\node[box=image 9]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\node[box=image 10]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};

\node[box=image 11,
      below=of A-6]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck-portrait}};% A-11
\node[box=image 12]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck-portrait}};
\node[box=image 13]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck-portrait}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: without tikz i can achieve it with tabular* but i want to know if i could achieve it in tikz.

Comment: @user1850133, of course you can. But I prefer simple(r) solutions .  See addendum to answer (will appear ASAP) .

Comment: @user1850133, done!

Comment: do you know what name is given to the extra node created when using "label="? I need to put some content at the bottom of this chain. For the first entry of the last row i did "\node[box=image 11,below=of A-6] (lastrow) {\include..." but here "lastrow" is for the image, not the text (caption) added at the bottom as label.

Comment: Sorry for late replay. I didn't see your comment before. And again sorry, I don't understand what you like to achieve. Add more text in label "image 11"? Or you like to have some caption on bottom of gallery?

Comment: by using "label=..." tikz adds another node to the main one. I want to know its name.

Comment: @user1850133, so far labels are not named. For this you need to change style `box`. However, you can add box below node A-11 for example as follows: 
`\node[draw, below right=5ex and 0ex of A-11.south west] {node with long text below of a-11};`. Anyway, if you have new problems, please ask new question. As far as I see, this one is solved, so one of received answers you should accept ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I know you want to use `TiKZ` but with a `tcbraster` (from `tcolorbox` package) you can do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=4, enhanced, sharp corners, halign title=center, flip title={boxsep=1mm}, blank, colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black]
\foreach \i in {a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c}{
\tcbincludegraphics[title=image~\thetcbrasternum]{example-image-\i}}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

The original code used a `foreach` loop just for covenience. of course it's possible to declare each individual image with its particular caption. As an alternative, it's also possible to use a `foreach` loop with pairs `image-file/caption`.

and about the possibility of captions below two or more figures, it's also possible with `multicolum` elements. Following code shows it. It's necessary to better adjust inner image sizes, but this is just  an example of use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=4, enhanced, sharp corners, halign title=center, flip title={boxsep=1mm}, blank, colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black]
% For each with automaticaly declared captions
\foreach \i in {a,b,c,a,b,c}{
\tcbincludegraphics[title=image~\thetcbrasternum]{example-image-\i}}
% Individual declaration
\tcbincludegraphics[title=Special title]{example-image}
% for each with pairs image-file/caption
\foreach \i/\j in {example-image-a/First, example-image-c/Second, example-image/Third}
{\tcbincludegraphics[title=\j]{\i}}
% Special box with two images with one caption. It needs more work
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2, title=Experiment]{\includegraphics[width={.495\linewidth}]{example-image-a}\hfill\includegraphics[width={.495\linewidth}]{example-image-b}}

\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what if my image-caption pairs are like this {sun.png}{sun}, {moon.png}{sky during night}, {flyingman.png}{man in the sky}...?

Comment: did you try with "title=\i" and check boxes horizontal alignment between a and b? or b and c?

Comment: @user1850133 i've updated the answer trying to solve your questions.

Comment: i noticed alignment defect because of the difference of the max height of the letters in the caption. It seems to be the case in your image.

Comment: @user1850133 You can add `\strut` command to all titles and they will have equal height

Comment: yes it works. Can you do something for the first image in the first row, it is sightly away on the right?

Comment: @user1850133 It's a spureous white space after the `foreach`. Write `\foreach \i in {a,b,c,a,b,c}{%` (with `%` at the end of the line